# GitLab CI/CD - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a multi file pipeline, this is the main job:

```
include:
  - local: "partials/scripts/setup_ssh_key.yaml"
  - local: "partials/scripts/change_document_root.yaml"
  - local: "partials/scripts/fix_permissions.yaml"
  - local: "partials/scripts/remove_db_folder.yaml"

.deploy.contabo:
  image: gotechnies/alpine-ssh
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - !reference [.snippets, setup_ssh_key]
  script:
    - scp -P $SSH_PORT artifact.zip $SSH_USER@$SERVER_IP:~/$SITE_FOLDER/app.zip
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SSH_PORT "cd ~/$SITE_FOLDER; rm -rf _old; rm -rf temp; mkdir temp; unzip -q app.zip -d ./temp; rm -f app.zip;"
    - >
      ssh $SSH_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SSH_PORT "
      cd ~/$SITE_FOLDER;
      cp -a ./$DOCUMENT_ROOT/wp-config.php ./temp/wp-config.php;
      cp -a ./$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess ./temp/.htaccess;
      cd ./temp;
      wp db reset --yes;
      wp db import DB/wordpress.sql;
      wp search-replace 'http://localhost' 'https://$SITE_URL' --all-tables --report-changed-only;
      "
  after_script:
    - !reference [.snippets, change_document_root]
    - !reference [.snippets, fix_permissions]
    - !reference [.snippets, remove_db_folder]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

in the `before_script` I add the public key that is stored in GitLab variables:

```
.snippets:
  setup_ssh_key:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

This is the first reference in after_script:

```
.snippets:
  change_document_root:
    - >
      ssh $SSH_USER@$SERVER_IP -p $SSH_PORT "
        cd ~/$SITE_FOLDER;
        mv $DOCUMENT_ROOT _old;
        mv temp $DOCUMENT_ROOT;
      "
```

The problem is that the job ends with success even if the server deny the connection:

[image]

It says Permission denied (publickey) on after_scripts. But as you can see in the job my pipeline already use ssh to connect the server in the scripts section and it runs with no issue.
Any clue why it fails on after_scripts?

Comment: `after_script` runs in a new shell. So any variables you exported in your `script`/`before_script` will not be present. At a glance, I'm guessing that's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, any docs about the new shell?